# How to add "No index" meta tag for all the environments other than prod in AEM6.3?

Tags: aem

I need to add the "**No index" meta tag** in the head section of my html pages for all the environments (stage, qa etc) other than prod/live site to avoid those environments to be searched by search engines.

I am planning to use the "**runmodes**" to check the environments and put the condition for each environment and don't add the "no index" for the prod runmode.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than change behavior between your production and pre-production environments, you could change the context in which the applications are deployed.

The following options come to mind:

1. Do not allow your pre-production environment to be accessed publicly. (e.g. do not give your pre-production environment a public IP address, limit access to same network/VPN, etc.)
2. If you have Apache in front of AEM, I assume you would have a different Apache instance or different Apache vhost for each environment. You could configure your pre-production vhost to always add [the `x-robots: noindex` header](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag#using-the-x-robots-tag-http-header)

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to create a Use class/Sling model, wire in the `SlingSettingsService` [docs here](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/settings/SlingSettingsService.html) and then use `SlingSettingsService#getRunModes()` to get all runmodes and check for the desired runmode.

here is a simple sling model to check for prod runmode. You can add more checks based on your specific runmodes in the same fashion.

```
@Model(adaptables = {SlingHttpServletRequest.class})
public class AbstractFacilityComponent
{

  @OSGiService SlingSettingsService slingSettings;


  boolean isProd;

  @PostConstruct
  protected void postConstruct()
  {
    Set<String> runmodes = slingSettings.getRunModes();
    isProd = runmodes.contains("prod");

    return;
  } 

  public boolean isProd(){ return isProd; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should keep your non prod environments private. If google can index your staging or dev instances, then everyone else can access it too. From my point of view this is a high security risk.